# Playing sound in Flutter simultaneously

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-android

How can I play a sound in Flutter while still allowing, say a different music player application to continue playing music at the same time?

Currently I have the following code in my application, however it stops playing music from a different application when it gets called.

```
 _playSound(String sound) async {
     String ringerStatus = await SoundMode.ringerModeStatus;
     if (ringerStatus.contains("Normal Mode")) {
        return await player.play(sound);
     }
 }
```